# Magento adding product attribute in install script

Tags: php, xml, magento, attributes, installation

I want to add attribute to product price in Magento by install script. It should be a select field displayed in the Prices group and consists of two values - Yes and No. But I faced with a problem: my code doesn't work. Despite long looking through my code, the problem still doesn't fixed. Could you help me with this issue? Here is my code:

Part of /../etc/config.xml

```
<module>
        <My_Module
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </My_Module
    </module>
    <global>
        <models>
            <module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </module>
        </models>
            <resources>              
                <module_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>My_Module</module>
                       <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_setup</use>
                    </connection>
                </module_setup>
                <module_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
                </module_write>
                <module_read>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_read</use>
                    </connection>
                </module_read>
            </resources>
    </global>
```

/../sql/mymodule_setup/mysql4-install-1.0.0.php

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();


$setup->addAttribute("catalog_product", "price_offer",  array(
                    'group'         => 'Prices', 
                    'type'          => 'int',
                    'attribute_set' =>  'Price',
                    'backend'       => '',
                    'frontend'      => '',
                    'label'         => 'Allow Price Offer',
                    'input'         => 'select',
                    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'backend'    => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_array',
                    'visible'       => true,
                    'required'      => false,
                    'user_defined'  => true,
                    'default'       => '0',
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable',
                    'sort_order'    => 10,
                    'is_configurable' => 1,
                    'option'     => array (
                        'values' => array(
                            0 => 'No',
                            1 => 'Yes',
                        )
                    ),

    ));

$installer->endSetup();
```

Finally, here is /etc/modules/My_Module.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <My_Module>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </My_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Hope you help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have error in this class Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
Use ($installer is Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup class)

```
$installer->addAttribute( ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed the script. Now it looks like:
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->addAttribute(....);
$installer->endSetup();
But, unfortunately your solution didn't solve the problem. My module still even hasn't been written into core_resource.

Comment: Take out the addAttribute in your install script and see if it writes into the 'core_resource' table. After the setup script runs, should be a row with 'module_setup 1.0.0 1.0.0' in core_resource. If not, then your module is not setup correctly. Check your config.xml.

Comment: Don't use `startSetup();` unless you really need it. You would know if you would need it.

Comment: @DavidTay, the record has been created in this table after fixing syntax mistake in config.xml: instead <modules></..> i had written <module></..> But, all the same, the attribute hasn't been created. I am checking this out by looking into the table 'eav_attribute'. Also, in config.xml I was trying put into resource class and Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup and Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup and result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Your install script is definitely not the problem, the code formatting is simple. Looks like it is something with a config thats causing your problem. Do you mean that the install script isn't running so the database isn't updated or is the value in the database and not showing up on Magento?

For your config, I think you need a database handler so you need a resource model:

```
<module>
    <My_Module>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </My_Module>
</module>
<global>
    <models>
        <module>
            <class>My_Module_Model</class>
        </module>
    </models>
    <my>
        <class>My_Module_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>my_module_resource</resourceModel>
    </my>
    <my_module_resource>
        <class>my_module_Model_Mysql4</class>
    </my_module_resource>
        <resources>              
            <module_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>My_Module</module>
                   <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </module_setup>
            <module_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </module_write>
            <module_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </module_read>
        </resources>
</global>
```

Remember to add a resource model under Model folder if you follow this code.

Comment: Thanks for your help @cleong , but I really don't understand why I need this resource handler while my module doesn't create new tables and doesn't work with custom tables. All I need is to add new attribute by my module version and use products with that.

Comment: Well the a resource is just the database handler for magento, if your doing any db work you need a handler to connect

Comment: But I really don't understand what do I need to take down into resource class in this case. For example, I will add a resource folder: /My/Module/Model/Mysql4. Should I put into this folder any .php file? And, in case "yes", what should I write in this file?

Comment: Make a module.php under resource, it will be the database handler class for the module model

Comment: I put into this file next code:
class My_Module_Model_Mysql4_Module extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('catalog/product', 'entity_id');
    }
}
and config.xml became:
<models>
   <module>
    <class>My_Modulle_Model</class>
                                 <resourceModel>module_mysql4</resourceModel>
   </module>
                        <module_mysql4>My_Module_Model_Mysql4</module_mysql4>
  </models>

Am I right understand your solution?